# IIS6.0 FTP - can't list files in browser

Tags: windows-server-2008, ftp

I'm trying to setup a new FTP server using IIS 6.0 on Windows 2008.  If I use an FTP client (such as Windows XP's built-in FTP command at the command line), I can login and browse files/directories without problems.

If I access the FTP site via a web browser (Tried FireFox and IE), I can login, but it won't list files.  IE gives a "can't display this webpage error" and FireFox gives the normal Index of ftp://fileserver/, but shows no files.

I'm testing on our intranet to rule out firewall/router issues, but that should obviously not matter since command-line FTP works fine.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Ok, it seems to be an issue with Passive-mode FTP.  I tried a third-party FTP program (WinSCP) and it worked in Active mode, but not Passive.  I'm still researching, but it's not a firewall issue (disabled windows firewall on my laptop and the server), but it is a network issue (maybe an IIS setting?), because it works fine in a browser *on* the server, just not remote.

Comment: What is between your client and the IIS server?  Any other firewalls?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the FTP client is using PASV transfers automatically.

Do you have both the FTP and FTP-DATA ports (20 and 21) opened on the firewall?

There is an option in IE to use PASV transfers under Advanced options that you can check/uncheck.

More information here: http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html

Sounds like the firewall is getting in the way and you should configure your browsers and FTP clients to use PASV FTP

Comment: I was looking along the same lines.  Didn't help, but upvoting, as that's the same direction I was looking :)